# SQLite Multiple Attached rather than single large database

Tags: sqlite

I'm going to end-up with a rather large database CubeSQLite in the cloud and cloned on the local machine. In my current databases I already have 185 tables and growing. I store them in 6 SQLite databases and begin by attaching them together Using the ATTACH DATABASE command. There are views that point to information in other databases and, as a result, Navicat won't open the SQLite tables individually. It finds them to be corrupted, although they are not and are working fine.

My actual question is this:
Considering the potential size of the files, is it better/faster/slower to do it this way or to put them all into one really large SQLite DB?

Comment: Why multiple files? What do you think you gain from this?

Comment: Good question. Scalability and some naming advantage. For example I might have tables for contacts, employees, customers, etc. Each of these would have linked tables that contain email, address, phone. With them all in different files, I can give the the same table name and refer to them by their db.table name. The naming conventions could remain the same over the entire system.

Comment: Scalability? You store them on different disks, and have an I/O system that can handle the bandwidth? As for the names, why not use `customer_emails`?

Comment: That's certainly a possibility. It would certainly be easier to write if all the tables were in the same file. I appreciate your advice. Anyone have an argument for different files?